# Как получить значение определенного input

Tags: jquery

При нажатии на ссылку "Клиент 1" или "Клиент 2" или любой другой клиент, в инпут client вставляется наименование клиента как написано в ссылке , а в инпут contract_srch должно вставляться значение скрытого инпут contr_id. Но при нажатии вставляется текст [object Object]. Как это можно сделать?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.search_result a', function() {
  $('#client').val($(this).text());
  var $contr_id = $('.search_result input').val($(this).text());

  $('#contract_srch').val($contr_id);

  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search_result">
  <a href="#">Клиент № 1</a>
  <input type="hidden" name="contr_id" id="1" value="1">
</div>
<div class="search_result">
  <a href="#">Клиент № 2</a>
  <input type="hidden" name="contr_id" id="2" value="2">
</div>
```

```
<div class="search_box"> 
    <input type="text" name="client" id="client">  
    <input type="text" name="contract_srch" id="contract_srch">          
    <div id="search_box-result"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ну так у Вас 2 поля с именем "contr_id" - вот Вы и получаете объект из 2 значений. `val('текст')` не вернет в ответ переменной этот текст, а сами найденные элементы. Но вопрос тут другой: а нафига? Вы и так записываете везде `$(this).text()`, так и вписывайте в `#contract_srch` это же.

Answer (score 0):

Немного поправил код, изменил получение данных из `input` и передачу их в соответствующие поля. Но я бы изменил поля `name="contr_id"` на `name="contr_id_1"`

```js
$(document).on('click', '.search_result a', function() {
 $('#contract_srch').val($(this).closest('.search_result').find('input').val());
 $('#client').val($(this).closest('.search_result').find('a').text());
     return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div class="search_result">
          <a href="#">Клиент № 1</a>
          <input type="hidden" name="contr_id" id="1" value="1">
       </div>
       <div class="search_result">
          <a href="#">Клиент № 2</a>
          <input type="hidden" name="contr_id" id="2" value="2">
        </div>
<div class="search_box"> 
    <input type="text" name="client" id="client">  
    <input type="text" name="contract_srch" id="contract_srch">          
    <div id="search_box-result"></div>
</div>
```